# What is this little box at the end of my code in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

This little box circled in blue[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the end of file marker.  You will not see it if you switch off whitespace characters